# Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)

Tags: django, typescript, next.js, oauth-2.0, next.js14

This is the code I copied from some blogs for google authentication OAUTH 2.0. The code was based on django backend and react.js frontend. In my project I am using django as backend but next.js 14 using typescript as frontend.

When `openGoogleLoginPage` function is called after clicking a button google login page gets opened but in console `Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)` error is shown.

And After clicking on any account it sends get request to server but in django server `"GET /api/v1/auth/login/google/?code=4%2F0AfJohXm69xHTNpnP3QX8CbhwTO18s4XZIFERfUDq_pfhaOgCYPm6jpf3XRyxTg_ziIB8Lw&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=2&prompt=consent HTTP/1.1" 500 103892` is shown

```
 const Home = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(localStorage.getItem('goggleFirstName'))

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedUsername = localStorage.getItem("user_goggle");
    if (storedUsername) {
      setUsername(storedUsername);
    }
  }, []);
  const openGoogleLoginPage = useCallback(() => {
    const googleAuthUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";

    const scope = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
     ].join(" ");

    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      response_type: "code",
      client_id: REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      redirect_uri: `${REACT_APP_GOGGLE_REDIRECT_URL_ENDPOINT}/google`,
      prompt: "select_account",
      access_type: "offline",
      scope,
    });

    const url = `${googleAuthUrl}?${params}`;

    window.location.href = url;
  }, []);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.clear(); // Clear localStorage when the button is clicked
    setUsername("")
  };
```

The tutorial which I was following is [this](https://medium.com/codex/building-a-custom-google-authentication-system-with-django-rest-framework-and-reactjs-i-925d2ba9258).

I have been stuck with this problem for a couple of days. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this using next.js 14 typescript.